# Scratch Org support for Person Accounts?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm trying to create a scratch org with the following definition so that Person Accounts:

```
{
    "orgName": "Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["PersonAccounts"]
    }
}
```

According to the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm this is a supported feature.

However, when I try running:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Unsupported org preference: PersonAccounts.
```

Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ended up realizing `orgPreferences` are different than `features`. So the definition ended up looking like this:

```
{
    "orgName": "Company",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["PersonAccounts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be warned, however, that packaging and `source:push/pull` do not work for any org if the source contains customizations specific to Person Accounts.

I guess you have to deploy the source with meta-data API, but as far as I know you can not use the SFDX to `package:version` & `install` anything that contains Person Accounts - Related source (i.e. RecordTypes in a PersonAccount - Folder or Source that references `__pc` fields).

Comment: J. Lietzau, Do you encounter this issue even if you specify this scratch org definition file in the --definitionfile argument of package:version:create? Dileep